# How to upload a file from server filesystem to SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have this MVC3 Application where I generate a file within `~/Content/Resource` directory, so I need to upload it to database if user picks that option. I have all rest of the logic ready. Just unsure how to approach this.

I have `byte[]` field in my model ready for it, and have a generated file ready for upload just no idea how to pass the file from server to SQL server... Kinda confused since this won't be a `PostedFIle` so dunno how to treat it...

Comment: What kind of ORM framework (if any) do you use?

Comment: Entity Framework 4.1 CodeFirst. If thats your answer.

Comment: I am not familiar with that one. Anyway, you can always get by with storing just the path to the file (simple text field) to the database and not the content itself.

Comment: I think you should put some code here. I understand that users generate a file, and your application store it in the file system. Do you want that your application save that file in the DB at the same time? or Do you want that users select the file generated previously and stored it in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a simple solution. Just converted generated file to `byte[]` and it worked spot on.
This is the code

```
//Method for generating XML file
GenerateXML();

FileStream stream = new FileStream(createPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

//Reading binary data into byte[]
byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
reader.Close();
stream.Close();

// Saving byte[] to models byte[] field
release.XMLFile = file;
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's article explaining in detail how to do what you're looking for.
You might take their approach completely, or if you have something ready of your own, just take those parts you're looking for

[Upload and Download files in database using MVC & Linq to SQL](http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/11/16/Upload-and-Download-files-in-database-using-MVC-Linq-to-SQL.aspx)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Maybe I haven't made my question clear enough, sorry. But what I want is to upload file from server file system (meaning it is an application generated file not from users computer) to sql server that is on the same server machine. And it's not an image file.